# Can I generate country in dimension in Tableau?

Tags: geocoding, tableau-api, dimensions, country

I'm doing airlines analytics in Tableau. I only have airport names but not country names. Airport codes can be turned into geographic airport, so they're automatically drafted on a map. Then I want to filter out only US flights. Can I generate a country dimension based on the map so that I can select US?

Comment: You should find a separate data set that maps country names/codes to airports and then merge that onto your data set to filter.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try that out. Thanks!